# jq: find and replace null with zero (0)

Tags: json, null, jq

Given this output:

```
cat file.json | jq -cr '.[] | .name, .time.total, .dueOn'
```

I get the output:

```
Task one
35160
2020-08-14
Task two
null
null
Task three
null
null
Task 4
2280
null
```

The **time.total** value of "null" I'd like to change to 0, so I can perform math on it. (I intend to divide by 3600 to covert the value to hours, e.g 1.25)

I've read countless SE articles, and no doubt my jq chops aren't where they need to be. But I hope there's a basic solution for this!

Desired output would be:

```
Task one
35160
2020-08-14
Task two
0
null
Task three
0
null
Task 4
2280
null
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `.time.total`, you could write:

```
(.time.total // 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work. I assume that's the Alternative Operator? What does that mean in plain English? Is it: if value is NOT null, retain the value. If it IS null, change it to zero?

Comment: Very roughly:  x // y means `if x is false or null or empty then y else x`. Please see https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#or-versus-

Comment: @CreativeArc if you are still around, please come back and mark this answer as accepted. Thank you, peak, this was just what I needed.